# using an object from one specific thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, com

i have a COM object that i am using in dotnet and i have to call it always on the same thread.  The issue is that conceptually it is being for multiple things throughout the program.  What is the best way for ensuring that all uses of this object on called on this one specific background thread?  Example code would be great.

Comment: You did not explain why you need to call the object from the same thread. There can be many reasons, and each one yields a slightly different recommendation.

My questions: Does the object itself care? Is it STA? Is this a condition for your application? Is the object involved in window/GDI manipulation of some sort? Is your "specific thread" the main UI thread?

Comment: i need to do this because the object is a COM object so it always has to be called on the same thread.

Comment: There is nothing in COM that requires all objects to be called from the same thread just because they are COM objects. In fact, there are ways to call most COM objects from any thread you want. Some objects do have that requirement, and sometimes the client app does. Let me be more specific: a) Do you know if it's an STA object, MTA, or free-threaded? b) Do you control the source code of the object? c) Does *your* client program care about which thread is used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could start a thread at program startup, which should handle all the COM interaction. Then you could have a wrapper object which pushes tasks onto a queue for the thread to handle.

The wrapper could contain synchronization code in order to hide the multi-threadedness to callers (ie. expose the wrapped calls as synchronous methods).

If this is a WinForms project, perhaps you could cut corners by simply using the GUI thread and the Control.Invoke method. (But if the calls take a long time, it is not a good idea, since you would be blocking the UI during the call).

Answer (score 0):

If you can the object under STA then it is granted to be called on the same thread.
For that you need to add [STAThreadAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.stathreadattribute.aspx) on your Main.
The only problem is that **ALL** COM objects will be handled that way.

Answer (score 0):

In order to do this, you must first establish a way to get a particular call onto a particular thread.  .Net has several built-in mechanisms for doing this but I find the easiest is the SynchronizationContext class.  Both WinForms and WPF establish a SynchronizationContext instance for any thread where they are running a message loop.

So I would ...

- Start a new thread for the object
- Create a hidden WinForms or WPF window and run it
- Grab the SynchronizationContext for that thread
- Create the COM object on that thread

Now you have a location for the COM object and the means to get a call back onto the correct thread.  The next step would be to create a proxy object.  This object should have all of the methods for the COM object (and potentially just implement the COM interface).  It would then take every method call and proxy the call off to the real COM object using the synchronization context.

```
public class Foo {
  private ComFoo _com;
  private SynchronizationContext _context;
  public void Bar() { 
    _context.Send(notUsed => _com.Bar(););
  }
}
```

Comment: @JaredPar, that's the start of a very good answer, but I, personally, would need more to get it working quickly. Maybe others would, as well. Can you show what the hidden window is about? How to assoc. the thread with it?